# Is the payable only for contract address or also for account address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm learning solidity by official docs, one thing I'm not sure is that the address payable concept is only for contract address?
Since I think the account address, as msg.sender, can auto receive token, isn't it?

BTW, if the payable is for contract address, then the following code is useless, right?

```
address private _owner = 0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465Eab2;
address payable owner = payable(_owner);

address immutable owner2 = payable(msg.sender);
```

Comment: To my surprise, it appears you aren't required to type an address as payable to send it native tokens when using the max-gas-then-refund method:

address immutable private owner = msg.sender;

(bool sent, bytes memory data) = owner.call{value: amountToSend}("");
require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used for both - contract address as well as account address.

`address payable` type (extension of `address` type) enables calling the native `.transfer()` function on the type, to transfer the native tokens (ETH on EThereum, MATIC on Poylgon, ...) to the specified address.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#address

So in the example that you shared, `_owner` is not `payable` and your code is not able to send it ETH. While `owner` and `owner2` are `payable` so your code can send them ETH.

*Note: Do not confuse the native transfer with ERC-20 transfer function. Those are two separate functions, even though they have the same name - but they accept different arguments and are member functions of different types.*

---

There's one further condition for contract receivers. The receiving contract needs to implement either the `receive()` or payable `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions) in order to be able to accept the transfer.

Comment: Thanks, I think my misunderstanding is in the difference between native transfer and  ERC-20 transfer.
One more question: when I have a metamask account address, why can others send me ETH? Is this account originally have payable modifier?

Comment: The `payable` extension is needed only in Solidity code, i.e. sending ETH from or through a contract... When you're sending ETH from an account address (for example from MetaMask), then the sender doesn't use any Solidity code, and for that matter no `payable` keyword.